# How to read the response returned to a Twilio function from another function?

Tags: api, salesforce, twilio, twilio-api

Really basic question - I'm calling a twilio function from another twilio function to retrieve the ID of a salesforce record. The following code is what gets returned from one function to another. I'm just trying to "read" the contents of the response to get the ID but can't seem to figure it out. I confirmed that the function returning the response works correctly (contains the right data.)

Help is much appreciated!

```
responsebody
2020-11-24T19:38:02.642Z    13c8fae2-5f74-40c2-942a-d6aa7ed85c48    INFO    Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'https://coxczsdlk-dffcat-8307.twil.io/sf-get-record',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }
```

Here's the code for the function returning this response - this line returns the correct ID - response.body.records[0].Id

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');
let globalCallback;

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    globalCallback = callback;
    console.log("Starting");
    console.log("event: ", event);
    run(context.DOMAIN_NAME, event);
};

function run(domain, event){
    request({
        uri: `https://${domain}/sf-access-token`,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if(res.statusCode == 200){
            // Received Access Token. Now build and send the request
            processRequest(JSON.parse(body), event);
        } else{
            globalCallback(`Error getting token: ${res.body}`);
        }
    });
}

function processRequest(sfAuthReponse, event){
   // if(validateRequest(event)) {
        var options = {
            // uri: `${sfAuthReponse.instance_url}/services/data/v43.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+From+${event.objectAPIName}+WHERE+callSID__c='${event.callSID}'`,
            uri: `${sfAuthReponse.instance_url}/services/data/v43.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+From+Case+WHERE+callSID__c='1'`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sfAuthReponse.access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: event.fields,
            json:true,
            method: 'GET'
        };
    
        request(options, processResponse);
  //  }
}

function validateRequest(event) {
    let valid = false;
    let validationMessage;
    
    if(!event.objectAPIName || event.objectAPIName.trim().length === 0) {
        validationMessage = "Parameter, objectAPIName, was not set in the JSON Request Body. Provide the SF API Name of the object to create";
    } else if (!event.fields) {
        validationMessage = "Parameter, fields, was not set in the JSON Request Body. Provide this parameter with a JSON value representing the fields to set when creating the SF object.";
    } else {
        valid = true;
    }
    
    if(!valid) {
        globalCallback(validationMessage);
    }
    
    return valid; // <== This will always return true since execution is terminated with the callback if invalid
}

function processResponse(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('response.body.records[0].Id');
        console.log(response.body.records[0].Id);

        // Successfully created new object. Response 201 from successful object creation
        //globalCallback(null, response.body.records[0].Id);
        globalCallback(null, response);
    } else{
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        console.log("Response: ", response);
        console.log(body);
        globalCallback(body);
    }
}
```

and here's some of the code for the first function calling the above function, not sure how to dot notation into the response.

```
fetch('https://casdflk-dsfdsfat-8707.twil.io/sf-get-record', {
                        headers: {
                           'Authorization': 'Basic ' + context.ENCODED_TWILIO_CREDS,
                           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: {
                            objectAPIName: 'Case',
                            callSID: '1',
                        }
                    
                 // callback(null,sid);
              }).then(record => {
                  
                    
                    console.log('recordbody11');
                    console.log(record.body);
                    return record;
```

Comment: Code please? Where are you calling the other function?

Comment: Edited my post, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `fetch`.

Fetch has a method `.json()` that you need to call on the response.

See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Is that your question or did I miss something?